# Sending a bitcoin transaction using bitcoinjs

Tags: javascript, transactions, bitcoin

Can someone please explain how I can send a bitcoin transaction using bitcoinjs??? I have setup two wallets using bitcoinjs.

I want to send 100000 satoshis from here:
**1G4iprWu7Q8tNbQLA8UBM2GearcnzwFrxM**

to here:
**1HsrKvboax8J3X1sgsRdWybEwnUNWsDw4Y**

In case it's needed here is the last transaction for [1G4iprWu7Q8tNbQLA8UBM2GearcnzwFrxM](https://blockchain.info/tx/4303caa91ca5a2236396af3bfae26b70a223a2bcee2fe8d23a7b24626c3c4bd2)

The code I am using is from the bitcoinjs.org website:

```
var tx = new bitcoin.TransactionBuilder()

// Add the input (who is paying):
// [previous transaction hash, index of the output to use]
var txId = 'aa94ab02c182214f090e99a0d57021caffd0f195a81c24602b1028b130b63e31'
tx.addInput(txId, 0)

// Add the output (who to pay to):
// [payee's address, amount in satoshis]
tx.addOutput("1Gokm82v6DmtwKEB8AiVhm82hyFSsEvBDK", 15000)

// Initialize a private key using WIF
var privateKeyWIF = 'L1uyy5qTuGrVXrmrsvHWHgVzW9kKdrp27wBC7Vs6nZDTF2BRUVwy'
var keyPair = bitcoin.ECPair.fromWIF(privateKeyWIF)

// Sign the first input with the new key
tx.sign(0, keyPair)

// Print transaction serialized as hex
console.log(tx.build().toHex())
// => 0100000001313eb630b128102b60241ca895f1d0ffca21 ...

// You could now push the transaction onto the Bitcoin network manually
// (see https://blockchain.info/pushtx)
```

Now I am assuming `var txId` is the transaction id from the last transaction [here](https://blockchain.info/tx/4303caa91ca5a2236396af3bfae26b70a223a2bcee2fe8d23a7b24626c3c4bd2)

Is the `tx.addInput`` where I put the fee? If so is 100 enough?

`tx.addOutput` is obvs so I am okay with that!

Is `var privateKeyWIF*` where I put the private key from the sending address?

No idea what `var keyPair` and `tx.sign` do!

Anyone who can help tell me where the details are suppposed to go would be much appreciated! For this example pretend my private key for the sender address is **5Kb8kLf9zgWQnogidDA76MzPL6TsZZY36hWXMssSzNydYXYB9KF**.

Cheers

Comment: have you read the [documentation](https://github.com/bitcoinjs/bitcoinjs-lib) - I'm assuming that's the library you are using

Comment: I remember this confusing me once upon-a-time so I gave up. Good luck

Comment: Yes I have read the documentation and I have had a number of attempts. The code I am using generates a transaction in hex format but not the desired transaction, I just need to know where it all goes

Answer (score 2):

```js
   let bitcoin = require('bitcoinjs-lib');
   const TESTNET = bitcoin.networks.testnet;
   const keyPair = bitcoin.ECPair.makeRandom({ network: TESTNET });
   const { address } = bitcoin.payments.p2pkh({
      pubkey: keyPair.publicKey,
      network: TESTNET,
   });;
   let wif = keyPair.toWIF()
// console.log(address, keyPair.publicKey.toString('hex') , keyPair.privateKey.toString('hex') , wif);

   let fkeyPair = bitcoin.ECPair.fromWIF(fwif , TESTNET);
   const result = await axios.get(`https://testnet.blockchain.info/rawaddr/${fAddress}`);
   let balance = result.data.final_balance;
   let latestTx = result.data.txs[0].hash;
   console.log('testAddress balance:' , balance);
   console.log('latest tx: ', latestTx);
   var txb = new bitcoin.TransactionBuilder(bitcoin.networks.testnet);
   let sendAmount = 15000;
   let fee = 26456;
   let whatIsLeft = balance - fee - sendAmount;
   txb.addInput(latestTx, 1);
   txb.addOutput(f2Address, sendAmount);
   txb.addOutput(f2Address, whatIsLeft);
   txb.sign(0, fkeyPair);
   let body = txb.build().toHex();
   console.log(body);
```

Answer (score 1):

A Bitcoin transaction typically references previous transaction outputs as new transaction inputs.

First you need to look at your previous transaction. As you can see [here](https://blockchain.info/tx/4303caa91ca5a2236396af3bfae26b70a223a2bcee2fe8d23a7b24626c3c4bd2) or in the snippet above the txId is:
`4303caa91ca5a2236396af3bfae26b70a223a2bcee2fe8d23a7b24626c3c4bd2`

```js
{
   "hash":"4303caa91ca5a2236396af3bfae26b70a223a2bcee2fe8d23a7b24626c3c4bd2",
   "ver":1,
   "vin_sz":1,
   "vout_sz":2,
   "size":225,
   "weight":900,
   "fee":18713,
   "relayed_by":"0.0.0.0",
   "lock_time":448506,
   "tx_index":7399058499716239,
   "double_spend":false,
   "time":1484590465,
   "block_index":448507,
   "block_height":448507,
   "inputs":[
      {
         "sequence":4294967294,
         "witness":"",
         "script":"47304402204fdab6f26efa32f49c79d8c91b5d42ea39760cff5afc34351f8595453bd3c9d102201ff8e25e4ababe3c3515617e90f97516cda50061ad0c02f215e4a008d580ede4012102e801e52ff6e7d1ad0bb46ef6732d8fcfae1e122a47ea5690e084b9fa4a73d106",
         "index":0,
         "prev_out":{
            "spent":true,
            "script":"76a914d7819c081b247a146922b8f90f89181b02a3c66f88ac",
            "spending_outpoints":[
               {
                  "tx_index":7399058499716239,
                  "n":0
               }
            ],
            "tx_index":356328836300976,
            "value":469871307,
            "addr":"1LeVYfpp1LQQUBqsmruVW6cMbYrZtmunPr",
            "n":1,
            "type":0
         }
      }
   ],
   "out":[
      {
         "type":0,
         "spent":true,
         "value":469352594,
         "spending_outpoints":[
            {
               "tx_index":5608049158171792,
               "n":0
            }
         ],
         "n":0,
         "tx_index":7399058499716239,
         "script":"76a9147adfb2779ee7710b0dffeff8fb77c82867ed43e588ac",
         "addr":"1CChR9sShAc61MNLhMoLzy87w5DwP6jRvv"
      },
      {
         "type":0,
         "spent":true,
         "value":500000,
         "spending_outpoints":[
            {
               "tx_index":8253272257190039,
               "n":0
            }
         ],
         "n":1,
         "tx_index":7399058499716239,
         "script":"76a914a53e0c670a2836baef1ea93de125f1fdd77370dd88ac",
         "addr":"1G4iprWu7Q8tNbQLA8UBM2GearcnzwFrxM"
      }
   ]
}
```

Your address `1G4iprWu7Q8tNbQLA8UBM2GearcnzwFrxM` shows up as the second output (`index 1`).

And the total amount at this address is `500000 satoshis`.

[image]

---

So, lets create our transaction

```
var txb = new bitcoin.TransactionBuilder()
txb.addInput('4303caa91ca5a2236396af3bfae26b70a223a2bcee2fe8d23a7b24626c3c4bd2', 1)
```

Now we will send 100000 satoshis

```
txb.addOutput('1cMh228HTCiwS8ZsaakH8A8wze1JR5ZsP', 100000)
```

We need to send the change to some address you own

```
txb.addOutput('1cMh228HTCiwS8ZsaakH8A8wze1JR5ZsP', 398130)
```

What is left is the miner fee. You can use [online services](https://estimatefee.com/) to estimate the ideal fee.

`(in)500000 Satoshis - (out)100000 - (out)398130  = (fee)1870`

Now we need to sign the transaction to confirm that you own the input address

```
var yourAddressPrivateKeyWIF = 'L1uyy5qTuGrVXrmrsvHWHgVzW9kKdrp27wBC7Vs6nZDTF2BRUVwy'
var yourAddresskeyPair = bitcoin.ECPair.fromWIF(yourAddressPrivateKeyWIF)
txb.sign(0, yourAddresskeyPair)
```

If you run `yourAddresskeyPair.getAdress()` the output should be your address `1G4iprWu7Q8tNbQLA8UBM2GearcnzwFrxM`

Now you can send your transaction to the network. Get raw transaction in hex format:

```
txb.build().toHex()
```

Paste the result here https://blockchain.info/pushtx or check other solutions here: https://github.com/bitcoinjs/bitcoinjs-lib/issues/839

Answer (score 1):

I am finding a lot of people are confused about that part - "how to post the transaction to the network". In short, you need access to a separate bitcoin core full node. The full nodes include JSON APIs that you post the raw transaction hex to, then the full node basically does the rest of the work for you behind the scenes (broadcasting over the gossip network to the other nodes, which then add the transaction into their own mempools, and then it waits for a miner to process it so it can be added into the blockchain).

There are two main ways to send the transaction to the network (sending it via the JSON RPC APIs in Bitcoin Core, or via the bitcoin-cli):

1. You could add a nodeJS library that allows you socket access to webservers, then invoke it as you would any other REST service from your nodeJS code.
2. For testing it is easier to use the "bitcoin-cli" that comes with the full node. Make sure your full node is running, SSH onto it, then invoke the sendrawtransaction command from within the bitcoin-cli. Specifically, from a UNIX prompt, it is one line:

- ```
  % bitcoin-cli sendrawtransaction 0000000001186f9f....00000000
  ```

That big long hex number IS the transaction HEX that your bitcoinjs code will have generated. The unconfirmed transaction should appear in your wallet within seconds. i.e. validated, but not yet confirmed.

Answer (score -1):

#### wif

First understand what [wif format](https://bitcoin.org/en/developer-guide#wallet-import-format-wif) is.

#### inputs

[From github](https://github.com/bitcoinjs/bitcoinjs-lib/blob/d853806/test/integration/basic.js#L50) we have:

`Transaction.prototype.addInput = function (hash, index, sequence, scriptSig)`

so you have to pass the hash of the transaction and the index (which output will be your input) you should check [what a bitcoin tx is](https://bitcoin.org/en/developer-guide#transactions)

#### keypair

Not verified that, but probably `keyPair` is your Pk and pk.

#### signatures

Please verify also that because I did not, but logically `tx.sign(index, keyPair)`  should sign the tx [(SIGHASH_ALL)](https://bitcoin.org/en/developer-guide#term-sighash-all) for the input `index` with the private key in `keyPair`. If you have more than one input of course you must provide a signature for each one. Take a look at [mastering bitcoin](http://chimera.labs.oreilly.com/books/1234000001802/ch02.html#_constructing_a_transaction)

Comment: Thanks for the info although this doesn't explain how to push the transaction on to the network